# How to make a List variable constant in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In this code, I am trying to check what rooms are available at the time that has been entered by the user. To test whether the room is free, I change the roomname to all the options and do a clash check. The problem is, is when I change the room name, it also updates it on my list of existingBookings. Is there a way to make sure that the existingBookings do not change?

```
var existingBookings = _context.Bookings.ToList();
var booking = await _context.Bookings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BookingID == id);

List<Room> roomlist = new List<Room>();

roomlist = (from product in _context.Room
            select product).ToList();

List<Room> availableRooms = new List<Room>();

foreach (var item in roomlist)
{
    booking.RoomName = item.RoomName;

    if (BusinessLogic.BookingChecker.DoesBookingClash(booking, existingBookings) == null)
    {
        availableRooms.Insert(0, new Room { RoomID = item.RoomID, RoomName = item.RoomName });
    }

    booking.RoomName = "UNDEF";
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this, was to add a new bool field called proposed into the `Booking.cs` file. When creating the proposed booking, it will automatically set it to true. In my `DoesRoomBookingClash` I added an if statement to ignore a database entry if proposed was true. Once all the changes are made, proposed is set to false.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do so you have to create a new instance of the `Booking`. You can call the constructor and copy the necessary properties, or implement a [`ICloneable.Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
public class Booking : ICloneable
{
    public Booking Clone()
    {
        return new Booking() { RoomID = this.RoomID, etc. };
    }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }
}
```

Then you call it:

```
booking = booking.Clone();

// use the new booking instance.
```